# PDO insert into dynamic field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function in my class

```
public function insertnewRec($name,$lastname,$category){
  try{
     $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT into user (fname,lname,$category) values(?,?,?)');
     $cmd->execute(array($name,$lastname,$category));
    }
  catch(){}
}
```

I want to insert to a field base on the value of my category,example if the value of category is = left then the pdo statement should like this,

```
 insert into user(fname,lname,left) values etc.....
```

but it's not working.I get error sql syntax

```
$cmd = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT into user (fname,lname,$category) values(?,?,?)');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's a good practice to put all fields and table name into back ticks. The error should go away as soon as you do that.

Answer (score 1):

> *"example if the value of category is = left then the pdo statement should like this"*

That's because `left` is a MySQL reserved word:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Therefore, you will need to wrap `$category` in backticks:

```
INSERT into user (fname,lname,`$category`)
```

As is the word `right`, should you decide to also use that word.

- Consult the link above for a full list.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$category' in 'field list'

Comment: Use [double-quotes instead of single-quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) - as in `$cmd = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT into user (fname,lname, `$category`) values(?,?,?)");  (with the backticks around $category)

Comment: This must be one of the ones you memorized ;)

Answer (score -1):

You should create an new pdo object

```
// Replace `$category` with a parameter `:category`
  $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('INSERT into user (fname,lname,:category) values(?,?,?)');

// bind $category and pass it into the execute() call inside an array
   $cmd ->execute(array('category'=>$category));
```